# What's the correct flow the OneLogin Login API

Tags: api, authentication, onelogin

I'm busy writing a test harness that will validate a REST API I've been developing. In the normal usage the my REST API will be used by a Web application that is secured and authenticated by OneLogin. My test harness will therefore have to use OneLogin to authenticate before I can call my own functions. I'm struggling to understand the right workflow for logging through an API as my test harness does not have a browser. So far I've got:

1. Request an Authentication Token using the Client Id and Secret (https://developers.onelogin.com/api-docs/1/oauth20-tokens/generate-tokens)
2. Request a Session Token using the Authentication Token, Sub-Domain, user name and password (https://developers.onelogin.com/api-docs/1/users/create-session-login-token)

I'm not quite sure what do do with the Session Token. I **suspect** I might have to create a session (https://developers.onelogin.com/api-docs/1/users/create-session-via-token) but that appears to be using a different URL.

Any ideas?

**Updated:**

Here is the code that I'm using for that final step. I pass in the Session Token obtained in the previous step.

```
/** see https://developers.onelogin.com/api-docs/1/users/create-session-via-token */
public void createSession(String sessionToken) {
    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("https://admin.us.onelogin.com/session_via_api_token");
    List<NameValuePair> postParameters = new ArrayList<>();

    postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("session_token", sessionToken));

    try (CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().build()) {
        HttpEntity entity = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(postParameters);

        httpPost.setEntity(entity);

        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        int status = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

        System.out.println(status);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The status code returned is 302 and the response headers contain `Location: https://<my-company>.onelogin.com`.

I'm taking this to mean that the last call has failed for some reason and I'm being redirected back to the log-in page.

Answer (score 1):

You suspect right.

Basically, after your server makes the back-channel requests for the token, you have to hand the token off via the `front channel` (user's browser) so you can establish a session, get cookies, etc... using the `session_via_api_token` 'endpoint' (which is a totally different sort of API from the ones to get the token in the first place)

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I've updated the question with the code I was using for the step I wasn't sure about. I know there is something wrong with it, but after 2 days of trying I can't for the life of me see what!

Comment: Also: this is for a REST test harness - these is no browser involved.

Comment: This endpoint is designed to work via a redirect back to your originating page (so you can do an old-school form post) so the 302 might be normal.

If you set the CORS parameters properly when you create the token you can do this via cross-site REST:

For setting CORS header: https://developers.onelogin.com/api-docs/1/users/create-session-login-token  - (Custom-Allowed-Origin-Header-1) 

See the CORS example here: https://developers.onelogin.com/api-docs/1/samples/login-user-via-api - (Example CORS Post)

Comment: Sorry, but I've not not had any luck with this. I assume that the value I set the "Custom-Allowed-Origin-Header-1" is the URL that it would like to redirect me back to.

Comment: Close - It should be set to the URL of the page you're making the cross-site POST from.

Comment: Ah! That makes sense for interactive (web based) log in screens. In my case I'm calling the code from a headless Java application, so there is no URL. What should I put in?

Comment: You can't use it headless - Ultimately you have to create a session with OneLogin and that requires a browser to collect session cookies and all that other good stuff to launch web apps under SSO.

The very fact that the initial call to get the session token succeeded is enough to authenticate the user. If you want to be paranoid you could make an HTTP call to confirm OneLogin sets a session cookie being set but that strikes me as overkill

Comment: Ok, Thanks. I hoping that I could collect all the cookies myself so that I could pass them back to the REST interface in the same way that that the browser would. The trouble is that with out them the REST interface will (and should) fail to return any data.

Comment: @Stormcloud, were you able to get the session? I also receive 302 Found and in headers: sub_session_onelogin.com=BAh7...

Comment: @Dmitry Stril, I never managed to get this to work. Eventually I just gave up and accepted that we can't have test automation if we want to use OneLogin :-(